# How to access a list in a function in a class?

Tags: python

I have a list to which I am appending values. It's in a function which is in a class. How do I access it?

```py
class A:
   def __init__(self):
        #my variables

   def myfunction(self):
       myList = []
       for i in range(5):
          myList.append(i)


myobj = A()
myobj.myfunction()
```

I want to get the list myList.

Comment: It is only available in the local scope of the function, unless you call it `self.myList` and then you can get `myobj.myList` after calling `myobj.myfunction()`

Comment: Return the value of the list from your function and get the value by calling the function with class object.

Comment: Set the list as a property or attribute of the class. Then you can access it outside the class.

Comment: Thanks alec and Juhil. Makes sense. Should have been straightforward however I couldn't figured. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways.

---

#### 1. Make it attribute

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list = []

    def my_function(self):
        self.my_list = []
        for i in range(5):
            self.my_list.append(i)


a = A()
a.my_function()
print(a.my_list)
```

output:

```py
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

#### 2. Return the list

```py
class A:
    def my_function(self):
        my_list = []
        for i in range(5):
            my_list.append(i)
        return my_list


a = A()
result = a.my_function()
print(result)
```

output:

```py
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks @Boseong. I am new to OOP. That helped. I should have at least figured out the second way. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 4):

Better implementation would have been:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__myList =[]

    def myfunction(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.__myList.append(i)
    @property
    def myList(self):
        return self.__myList.copy()
```

And then using it as:

```
myobj = A()
myobj.myfunction()
print(myobj.myList)
```

Comment: Thanks @Chayan. I couldn't understand what the decorator is doing. Care to explain a bit?

Comment: @VaibhavSaxena You can visit https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property for a more detailed understanding of getters and setters using property decorator in python

Comment: @VaibhavSaxena - Essentially, the `@property` decorator is used to make a class attribute read-only.  So if the user tried to update the list `myobj.myList = ['new', 'stuff']` an error would be thrown saying you cannot set the property.